# A multiple choice question regarding the expression$ \frac{\int_{0}^{4\pi}e^t(\sin^6at+\cos^4at)\,dt}{\int_{0}^{\pi}e^t(\sin^6at+\cos^4at)\,dt}=L\,$.

Tags: calculus, integration, trigonometry

> The option(s) with the values of $a$ and $L$ that satisfy the following equation is(are)
>   $$
> \dfrac{\int_{0}^{4\pi}e^t(\sin^6at+\cos^4at)\,dt}{\int_{0}^{\pi}e^t(\sin^6at+\cos^4at)\,dt}=L\, ?
> $$
>   $$
> \textrm{A}. a = 2, \displaystyle L=\frac{e^{4\pi}-1}{e^\pi-1} \qquad
> \textrm{B}. a = 2, \displaystyle L=\frac{e^{4\pi}+1}{e^\pi+1}  
> $$
>   $$
> \textrm{C}. a = 4, \displaystyle L=\frac{e^{4\pi}-1}{e^\pi-1} \qquad
> \textrm{D}. a = 4, \displaystyle L=\frac{e^{4\pi}+1}{e^\pi+1}  
> $$

Here is the [image link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/O5D5C.png). 
This is a problem from JEE-Advanced 2015 paper 2 question. At present, I don't know how to approach it.

A few good hints would be appreciated.

Answer (score 7):

The key is surely that if $f(t)=f(t+\pi)$ for all $t$ then
$$\int_{k\pi}^{(k+1)\pi}e^t f(t)\,dt=e^{k\pi}\int_0^\pi e^tf(t)\,dt$$
for integers $k$.

Comment: +1. A very appropriate hint! In addition, the OP should be knowledgeable of the closed form for a finite geometric series once the numerator is simplified to help turn the final answer into one (or more) of the form(s) available in the multiple choice.

Comment: @Lord A little bit more perhaps would be better for me.

Comment: Abusing notation, the corollary is that $\int_0^{4\pi}=\int_0^\pi+\int_\pi^{2\pi}+\int_{2\pi}^{3\pi}+\int_{3\pi}^{4\pi}=(1+e^\pi+e^{2\pi}+e^{3\pi})\int_0^\pi$.